# How to 'Select Specific data, copy only certain columns and insert it into a different table?'

Tags: mysql

Currently, I find it time consuming to copy specific columns and values from `Table 1` and paste the values onto `Table 2` manually.

I have two tables ( In the same database ) like this:

[image]

[image]

How can I save time by doing the following? -

Grab specific ID from `Table 1`, in this case `1` and `2`.

and  copy just the `Pcode` & `Desc` values onto `Table 2`?

This is the end result I want to achieve (screenshot below)

The ID will be new, because its a new record. So technically I am updating `Table 2` with new values that I have copied from `Table 1`

[image]

Every column is varchar type column expect the Id's

Also, I am using MySql Workbench.

Comment: Any particular difficulty with just using a simple `INSERT INTO Table2 (...) SELECT ... FROM Table1` statement?  Also, you should try to avoid using `VARCHAR` to store identifiers (as per your statement _Every column is varchar type column_)

Comment: Thanks Martin, the ID is not a Varchar, Ill make an edit to my post

Comment: I would suggest a quick think about Database Design. You dont need to duplicate the table.

Comment: I know what you mean RiggsFolly, the 2 tables come from 2 different sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick;

```sql
INSERT INTO table2 (PCode, Desc)
SELECT Pcode, Desc 
 FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = 1 or table1.id = 2
```

Comment: `WHERE table1.id IN(1,2)` even neater

Comment: If I wanted to delete the the ones I have copied from `table 1` I would just simply insert an `and` with a query to go after that?